# what is deferent between get method and regular method dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Good day, I am new with dart and I have two questions here

1. what is deferent between (`double get getName => name`) , (`double getName => name`)
2. sometimes I see method name with "." when we use this concept and what we call it
   Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double get name{

}
```

is what is called a "Getter". It is a way of exposing a value to outside of that class, for instance if you have a private variable `_name` and you want it to be readable from the outside, but not changeable, you might use a `getter`

```
double getName(){

}
```

is just a normal function.
the arrow syntax is just a shortened version of returning a value.
So:

```
int get x => _x;
```

and

```
int get x {
return _x;
}
```

are essentially the same. For some more reading on functions and getters/setters, have a look at these links.

https://dev.to/newtonmunene_yg/dart-getters-and-setters-1c8f
https://zetcode.com/dart/function/ (also has a  section on arrow functions)

EDIT:

For your second question:

```
  factory LoginResponse.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => LoginResponse(
        user: User.fromJson(json["user"]),
        accessToken: json["access_token"],
      );
```

In that case, this is a named `factory` constructor with the name "fromJson" that  takes a `Map<String,dynamic>` and returns a `LoginResponse` that is being created using the `LoginResponse(user, accessToken)` constructor.

You would call it like so:

```
var response = new LoginResponse.fromJson(json);
```

More about named constructors here:

[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_classes.htm#:~:text=Dart%20defines%20a%20constructor%20with,constructor%20is%20provided%20for%20you](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_classes.htm#:%7E:text=Dart%20defines%20a%20constructor%20with,constructor%20is%20provided%20for%20you).

Comment: I get it thanks 
what about the second part of my question

Comment: @mustafahasria not exactly sure what you mean with the second part. Could you maybe add an example?

Comment: ```  factory LoginResponse.fromJson (Map<String, dynamic> json) => LoginResponse(
    user: User.fromJson(json["user"]),
    accessToken: json["access_token"],
  );
```

Comment: sorry but my comment it doesn't show as code IDK why

Comment: @mustafahasria I editted my answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

By using `double get getName => name` , you are defining 'getName' as a getter. Where you are requesting the value of getname from outside a class. Whenever you call `getName`, the value of `name` will be returned.

Regarding `double getName => name` , it should be written like this `double getName() => name`.
By using this, you are basically telling your code:

```
double getName(){
return name;}
```

Meaning, the value of getName is returned from a function.

If you wrote `double getname(int x) => x + name`
the will run as :

```
double getName(int x){
return x + name;}
```

Comment: so it's just syntax deferent for organize the code

Comment: No, it's much more than just syntax. I suggest you read about getters and setters.
In your question, your first code is a getter. The second code is a function\method that returns logic.